# How to use a specific channel with discord rewrite

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I have this bot that can tell you the amount of messages a certain user has sent in the given amount of time in the current channel, but I would like to be able to specify what channel to check the messages from and not just the current one. How would you do this?

My script so far:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


class AdminCommands(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command(aliases=["stats", "activity", "messages"])
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def check(self, ctx, duration=7, specified_channel=None, *, user):
        async with ctx.channel.typing():
            msg = await ctx.channel.send('Calculating...')
            await msg.add_reaction('')

            counter = 0
            # I want to change this line:  
            async for message in ctx.channel.history(limit=5000, after=datetime.today() - timedelta(days=duration)):
                if str(message.author) == str(user):
                    counter += 1

            await msg.remove_reaction('', member=message.author)
            if counter == 5000:
                await msg.edit(content=f'{user} has sent over 5000 messages in this channel in {duration} days!')
            else:
                await msg.edit(content=f'{user} has sent {str(counter)} message(s) in this channel in {duration} days.')


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(AdminCommands(client))
```

How do I make it so when a user passes in a channel it will check that channel and not the channel the message was sent to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify an argument type:

```py
async def check(self, ctx, duration=7, channel: discord.TextChannel=None, *, user: discord.Member=None):
    if not channel:
        channel = ctx.channel
    if not user:
        user = ctx.author
    # rest of your code
```

This is setting the argument types to their respective discord objects, which allows you to access their attributes.

In the example I've also added the conditions that if a user hasn't been specified, then it defaults to the command sender, and if a channel hasn't been specified, then the command's channel is used.

---

**References:**

- [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member)
- [`discord.TextChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel)